# Login php error

Tags: php

What am I doing wrong here? It says Database Count Failed (on the $count line in Process.php) without giving reason. When I take our the "or die" part of that line, it always displays "user account created" no matter which button I pressed and it doesn't actually create an account...

Form.php

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Forms</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="process.php" method="post">
        <label for="username">Email: </label>
        <input type="email" name="username" value="" id="username"/>
        <br/>
        <label for="password">Password: </label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="" id="password"/>
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign in"/>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign up"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Process.php

```
<?php
    //1. Create a database connection
    $connection = mysql_connect("localhost","web","1234") or die("Database connection failed: " . mysql_error());

    //2. Select a database to use
    $db_select = mysql_select_db("tongue", $connection) or  die("Database selection failed: " .mysql_error());
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form processing</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0-rc.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.0-rc.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = trim($_POST['password']);
        $hashed_password = sha1($password);

        $action = $_POST['submit'];

    //3. Select email, password from database
        $query = "
                SELECT email, password FROM user 
                WHERE email='$username' AND password='$hashed_password'";
        $user = mysql_query($query, $connection)
            or die ("Database query failed: ".mysql_error());

        $count = mysql_num_rows($user) or die ("Database count failed: ".mysql_error());

    //4. Authenticate user
        if ($count == 1) {
            if($action="Sign up"){
                echo "User already exists";
            } else if ($action="Sign in"){
                echo "User signed in";
            };
        } else if ($count == 0){
            if($action="Sign up"){
            $query = "
                INSERT INTO users (email, password)
                VALUES ('$username', '$hashed_password')";
            $signup = mysql_query($query, $connection);
            echo "User account created";
            } else if ($action ="Sign in"){
                echo "Username and/or password incorrect";
            };
        };


    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: as $count==0 is a legitimate state, which you go on to handle, there is no point having your code die() when $count is zero, is there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running this example:

```
$a = 0 OR die('foobar');
var_dump($a);
```

You will see, that the `OR die()` will be executed any time the value is [considered false](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php).

That said .. your code is quite bad.

- The script is open to an SQL injection
- You are using `mysql_*` API, which is more then 10 years old, and should not be used in any newly written code. Instead you should learn to use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli).
- It's pointless to select by both username and password, if you already have a unique username column
- This is not how you should hash your password
- Do not create new accounts without telling people beforehand. What if i make a mistake in my email address ?

This is something like how i would do it:

```
$connection = new PDO( 'mysql:host=hostname;dbname=tongue', 'web', '1234');
$connection->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false );

$statement = $connection->prepare('
     SELECT 
         email, 
         hash, -- instead of password, because thats what it is
         salt
     FROM user 
     WHERE email = :username
');
$statement->bindParam( ':username', $_POST['username'], PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
if ( $statement->execute() )
{
    $data = $statement->fetch( PDO::FETCH_OBJ );
}

if ( $data )
{
    $hash = crypt( $_POST['password'], '$2a$07$' . $data->salt . '$' );
    if ( $hash === $data->hash )
    {
        // user OK
    }
    else
    {
        // login failed 
    }
}
else
{
    //login failed
}
```

This is obviously a bit simplified version, because, if you read manual entry for ['crypt()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php), you will notice that the resulting hash already contains the original salt. You can extract if from it. But the intention was to make a point, not to add too much detail.

Also the `if` condition for login could have been wrapped into single if, because, when you do `if( $condition_1 && $condition_2 && $condition_3 )`, PHP will stop checking at the first failed condition.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I found this website which helps understanding PDO (http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html#3)

Comment: @LapMingLee , this might help also : http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
 $count = mysql_num_rows($user) or die ("Database count failed: ".mysql_error());
```

Will die when $count == 0, as 0 would be evaluated as false. Aborting on $count==0 is unnecessary as you handle the case where you get no rows back. Plus, you've already checked that the query executed successfully, so this is actually pretty unlikely to fail.

If do you want to check for failure, check the result is actually false, rather than 'falsy'

```
  $count = mysql_num_rows($user);
  if ($count === false)
  {
      die ("Database count failed: ".mysql_error());
  }
```

Note the use of `===` rather than `==`, this ensure we check both type and value.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you test the connection first using a simple `SELECT * FROM user` and printing out the elements. If the connection is OK, then there might be an error in your SQL query. The `$user` variable is supposed to contain a resource, and `mysql_num_rows()` will fail otherwise. Use `is_resource()` to verify that the object returned by `mysql_query()` is in fact valid.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the final code (thanks a lot @_tereko) :

```
<?php
        try{
        $username_signup = "Tst@gmail.com";
        $password_signup = "est";
        $hash = crypt($password_signup, '$3a$08$2'); // salt 

        $connection = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tongue', 'web', '1234');
        $connection -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $connection -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        function login ($query, $connect, $user) {
        $statement  =   $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement  ->  bindParam(':username', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  ->  execute();
        $data = $statement->fetch (PDO::FETCH_OBJ); // fetches the columns defined as $property
        return $data;
        }

        function create ($query, $connect, $user, $pass) {
        $statement  =   $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement  ->  bindParam(':username', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  ->  bindParam(':password', $pass, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  ->  execute();
        }

        $sql = 'SELECT email, hash FROM user WHERE email=:username'; // must be defined before calling

        if ($row = login ($sql, $connection, $username_signup)) {
            echo "Account already exists!";
        }
        else {
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO user(email, hash) VALUES (:username, :password)';
            create($sql, $connection, $username_signup, $password_signup);
            echo "account created";
        };


    $connection = null;

    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }

?>
```